# Can't install Jupyter Notebook using Windows PowerShell because pip won't upgrade to version 20.1

Tags: python, powershell, pip, jupyter-notebook, upgrade

[image]
I'm following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6aOqkmrrb4) to install Jupyter Notebook using Windows PowerShell. I entered the `scripts` folder and type `.\pip install jupyter`, and then it suggested uploading `pip` to version 20.1 first. Well, I typed `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` as suggested, but nothing happened. If I tried to install Jupyter Notebook again, it would just start a circle once again.

Things I have tried but don't work:

1. `.\pip3 install jupyter` as some other thread online says
2. doing all these in the `Python` folder (one level up)
3. `python -m pip install -U pip`, as suggested by the [official webpage of installing pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip)
4. add Path to Windows as instructed by [this blog](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)

Why does this happen? Isn't what I get when installing Python 3.8 the lastest version of pip? How can I actually upload it to version 20.1 now?

BTW, this is what my `Scripts` directory looks like now:
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: After you change the `Path`  variable and before you start `python -m pip install -U pip` do you start a new shell ?

Comment: @JPBlanc No, I didn't. Should I do that?

Comment: @JPBlanc Thank you so much! I manage to open Jupyter Notebook now!

Comment: I put my comment as an answer.

Comment: @JPBlanc Great! Accepted it! Thanks a lot! (I'm so stupid...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you change the Path variable and before you start `python -m pip install -U pip` you have to start a new shell.

It's because the `Path` you setup is not taken dynamicaly.

Comment: Thank you so much!